# Dexie & Angular 4: slow performance when selecting items

Tags: angular, observable, indexeddb, ngrx-effects, dexie

I'm having issues with selecting items (between 1.000 and 4.000) via a query from my IndexedDB with Dexie in an Angular 4 application.

There are only max 20.000 items in the tables, but the selection of these takes multiple seconds (5s on Chrome 61, up to (and more) than 20s on iOS 10 & iOS 11)

Below is my service that fetches two different tables and returns an Observable via `loadItems()`

```
@Injectable()
export class ItemService {

    private buildings: Dexie.Table<Building, string>;
    private people: Dexie.Table<Person, string>;

    private activeZip: string;

    constructor(
        private db: IndexeddbService,
    ) {
        this.buildings = this.db.table('buildings');
        this.people = this.db.table('people');
    }

    loadItems(): Observable<{
        buildings: Building[],
        people: Person[]
    }> {
        return Observable.combineLatest(
            this.loadBuildings(),
            this.loadPeople(),
        ).map(([buildings, people]) => {
            return {
                buildings,
                people
            };
        });
    }

    private loadBuildings(): Observable<Building[]> {
        return Observable.from(this.buildings.where('zip').equals(this.activeZip).toArray());
    }

    private loadPeople(): Observable<Person[]> {
        return Observable.from(this.people.where('zip').equals(this.activeZip).toArray());
    }
}
```

The resulting Observable is asynchronously handled with a ngrx effect, which dispatches an Action that writes the data to the state, so the component can render the information.

```
@Effect()
loadItems$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
    .ofType(actions.ActionTypes.LOAD_ITEMS)
    .map(_ => this.itemService.setActiveZip(this.localStorageService.getActiveZip()))
    .switchMap(_ => this.itemService.loadItems())
    .map(items => new actions.LoadItemsSuccessAction(items))
    .catch(error => Observable.of(new actions.LoadItemsFailAction(error)));
```

I've tried to "lazy-load" the items in chunks via https://github.com/raphinesse/dexie-batch, but the resulting batches took more than 500ms to arrive.

Where do I have a possible performance bottleneck? I've already tried to run this query outside of Angular's zones, but this did not yield and performance improvements.

Comment: You want to put 4000 items at the same time on the page?

Comment: Create a plunker

Comment: @alexKhymenko - no, the information is in the store and via a scroll directive I am only adding 50 items to the view once the user hit the bottom. Tried to load the items directly from the DB when the user hit the bottom, but even that's too slow on the iPads.

Comment: With that amount of rows, don't forget to add the `trackBy` function to that `*ngFor`, also that time that you have messured, was from the moment that you made the request until the data was loaded in the UI or was the time since you made the request until you get the response?

Comment: @camaron thanks for the tip with trackBy, did not know this feature yet. The measurement via console.time() showed that the Observable takes so long to complete, Chrome performance profiling showed, that not rendering is the problem, but scripting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a lot of time and debugging, I've identified the following Dexie PR which breaks the IndexedDB 2.0 getAll feature in Chrome and Safari: https://github.com/dfahlander/Dexie.js/pull/579

With a revert back to Dexie 2.0.0-beta.11 performance is increased around 10x times (raw database queries via cursor to getAll went from 600-700ms back to 60ms)

**Edit**: Dexie 2.0.1 has been released with a correct fix for this issue